# Disable ECO In Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi.net

How i can disable ECO in delphi .Net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Export these two registry branches to a text file so you can reenable ECO later if required.

```
HKCU\Software\Borland\BDS\4.0\Known IDE Packages\DelphiDotNet  
HKCU\Software\Borland\BDS\4.0\Known IDE Packages\CSharp
```

Inside those two branches you'll find keys called

```
$(BDS)\Bin\Borland.Eco.Delphi.IDE100.bpl  
$(BDS)\Bin\Borland.Eco.CS.IDE100.bpl
```

Delete those keys from the registry then start Delphi.